# Comparing two sets of data (x,y)

Tags: c#, dataset, interpolation

I have stored numerical data in lists with its coordinates (xValues, yValues), and if I want to compare (add, subtract, divide...) that set of data to another I have to be aware of that I can't compare if the xValues don't match (because there is nothing to compare with). So I need to interpolate linearly between the "missing" xValues, that actually exist in the other set and generate new points. Please check this picture:

[image]

The cyan squares on the red line represent the stored points (xValues2), and (generally) they won't match the other's set xValues (xValues1). The two squares on the green line are examples of the desired generated points. With them I can work with this two graphs without problem.

For linear interpolation It's pretty straightforward: If I have two points (x0,y0) and (x1,y1) and I want to add a new point between them given a "x2":

```
y2=y0+(x2-x0)*(y1-y0)/(x1-x0)
```

To make this work I think I have to implement something like this:

1. Create new lists (xValuesNew, yValuesNew).
2. Make a union between xValues1 and xValues2 (xValuesNew).
3. Check what are the differences between the original xValues1 and the xValuesNew.
4. For each new value found generate the "y" using the formula written above.
5. Put that 4 steps in a method and use it again but now with the set2.

I've been on this all day, trying to find an easy solution, maybe using Linq or lambda expressions but I'm not used to work with them and my lack of knowledge on that topics ishuge. Note that this operation will be made pretty often so I have to make it not too heavy. I've thought that it will be a good idea to generate a new list instead inserting points in the middle of the original for that reason.

Please if someone could guide me a little bit or tell me if there is a math library actually doing this would be great. Thank you.

---

EDIT: Sorry if I haven't explained me properly.

Here I have an example (done in Excel):

[image]

Note that I can't directly add together Series1 and Series2 (+) or any other operation because the X spacing in them is different. So what I want is to generate a new point in the Series1 when is needed.

For that I would like to simple use a linear interpolation. Say that I have P1(0,40) and P2(0,60) in series1, but in series2 I have a point (1,10). I need to generate a point P3 between P1 and P2 with (1,50) coordinates.

[image]

[image]

I was trying to do this with SkipWhile and comparing the next X value of both series, if XValue of series1 is lower, then add that XValue and corresponding YValue in the newSeries. Else use the XValue2 for generating an Y and add it to the newSeries. Here is one of my attempts (doesn't work):

```
List<double> series1X = new List<double> { 0, 2, 4, 6, 8 };
        List<double> series1Y = new List<double> { 120, 100, 110, 105, 70 };
        List<double> series2X = new List<double> { 0, 1, 7, 8,9 };

        List<double> newSeries1X = new List<double>();
        List<double> newSeries1Y = new List<double>();

  double lastX1 = series1X[series1X.Count()-1];
        int i = 0;

        while (next1X <= lastX1)
        {

            next2X = series2X.SkipWhile(p => p <= next1X).First();
            Console.WriteLine(next2X.ToString());

            if (next1X <= next2X)
            {

                newSeries1X.Add(series1X[i]);
                newSeries1Y.Add(series1Y[i]);
            }

            if (next2X < next1X)
            {

                while (next2X < next1X)
                {
                    newSeries1X.Add(next2X);
                    newY = series1Y[i] + (next2X - series1X[i]) * (series1Y[i + 1] - series1Y[i]) / (series1X[i + 1] - series1X[i]);
                    newSeries1Y.Add(newY);

                    next2X = series2X.SkipWhile(p => p <= next2X).First();
                }
            }


            next1X = series1X.SkipWhile(p => p <= next2X).First();
            Console.WriteLine(next1X.ToString());
            i++;

        }
```

It would be AWESOME to do this with your Zip method. But I have no idea how to write that condition in the predicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, I'd probably use an appropriate 'point' class that contains both the *x* and *y* coordinates instead of two separate lists for each coordinate. Then you can use the [`Zip`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698.aspx) method to quickly iterate through them:

```
IEnumerable<PointF> points0 = ...
IEnumerable<PointF> points0 = ...
float x2 = ...
IEnumerable<PointF> newPoints = point0.Zip(points1, 
    (p0, p1) => new PointF(p0.X, p0.Y + (x2-p0.X) * (p1.Y-p0.Y) / (p1.X-p0.X)));
```

This makes it easy to calculate a new set of points from your input data. If you just care about a single y-value, you can still do this with your current data, it will just look weird:

```
IEnumerable<double> y2values = 
    xValues1.Zip(yValues1, (x, y) => new { x, y }).Zip(
        xValues2.Zip(yValues2, (x, y) => new { x, y }),
        (p0, p1) => p0.y + (x2-p0.x) * (p1.y-p0.y) / (p1.x-p0.x));
```

<sub>I appologize if in the process of coding this answer I somehow mangled your math.</sub>

---

**Update**

Now that I have a better grasp on what you're trying to do, I don't think any Linq method will work out quite right. Here what I've come up with using indexes:

```
List<double> series1X = new List<double> {   0,   2,   4,   6,  8 };
List<double> series1Y = new List<double> { 120, 100, 110, 105, 70 };
List<double> series2X = new List<double> {   0,   1,   7,   8,  9 };

// in the worst case there are n + m new points
List<double> newSeries1X = new List<double>(series1X.Count + series2X.Count);
List<double> newSeries1Y = new List<double>(series1X.Count + series2X.Count);

int i = 0, j = 0;
for ( ; i < series1X.Count && j < series2X.Count; )
{
    if (series1X[i] <= series2X[j])
    {
        newSeries1X.Add(series1X[i]);
        newSeries1Y.Add(series1Y[i]);
        if (series1X[i] == series2X[j])
        {
            j++;
        }
        i++; 
    }
    else
    {
        int k = (i == 0) ? i : i - 1;
        // interpolate
        double y0 = series1Y[k];
        double y1 = series1Y[k + 1];
        double x0 = series1X[k];
        double x1 = series1X[k + 1];
        double y = y0 + (y1 - y0) * (series2X[j] - x0) / (x1 - x0);
        newSeries1X.Add(series2X[j]);
        newSeries1Y.Add(y);
        j++;
    }
}
for ( ; i < series1X.Count; i++)
{
    newSeries1X.Add(series1X[i]);
    newSeries1Y.Add(series1Y[i]);
}
for ( ; j < series2X.Count; j++)
{
    // interpolate
    double y0 = series1Y[i - 2];
    double y1 = series1Y[i - 1];
    double x0 = series1X[i - 2];
    double x1 = series1X[i - 1];
    double y = y0 + (y1 - y0) * (series2X[j] - x0) / (x1 - x0);
    newSeries1X.Add(series2X[j]);
    newSeries1Y.Add(y);
}
```

Output is

```
newSeries1X = {    0,    1,    2,    4,    6,    7,    8,    0 }
newSeries1Y = {  120,  110,  100,  110,  105, 87.5,   70, 52.5 }
```

This solution handles cases where the first `series2X[0] < series1X[0]` and when `series2X[n] > series1X[m]` by linearly 'projecting' the data outward from the first / last pair of points.

Here's another solution using enumerators (mostly), but it's not nearly as elegant as I'd hoped it would be. It could probably be improved a bit:

```
bool hasS1 = true, hasS2 = true, preinterp = true;
double x0 = 0, y0 = 0, x1 = 0, y1 = 0, x = 0, y = 0;
using(var s1xEnumerator = series1X.GetEnumerator())
using(var s1yEnumerator = series1Y.GetEnumerator())
using(var s2xEnumerator = series2X.GetEnumerator())
{
    hasS1 = s1xEnumerator.MoveNext();
    hasS2 = s2xEnumerator.MoveNext();
    s1yEnumerator.MoveNext();
    while(hasS1 && hasS2)
    {
        x1 = s1xEnumerator.Current;
        y1 = s1yEnumerator.Current;
        x = s2xEnumerator.Current;

        if (x1 <= x)
        {
            newSeries1X.Add(x1);
            newSeries1Y.Add(y1);
            hasS1 = s1xEnumerator.MoveNext();
            s1yEnumerator.MoveNext();
            preinterp = false;
            if (hasS1)
            {
                x0 = x1;
                y0 = y1;
            }
            if (x1 == x)
            {
                hasS2 = s2xEnumerator.MoveNext();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // we have to look ahead to get the next interval to interpolate before x0
            if (preinterp)
            {
                x0 = x1;
                y0 = y1;
                x1 = series1X[1]; // can't peek with enumerator
                y1 = series1Y[1]; 
                preinterp = false;
            }

            y = y0 + (y1 - y0) * (x - x0) / (x1 - x0);
            newSeries1X.Add(x);
            newSeries1Y.Add(y);
            hasS2 = s2xEnumerator.MoveNext();
        }
    }

    while(hasS1)
    {
        newSeries1X.Add(s1xEnumerator.Current);
        newSeries1Y.Add(s1yEnumerator.Current);
        hasS1 = s1xEnumerator.MoveNext();
        s1yEnumerator.MoveNext();
    }

    while(hasS2)
    {
        x = s2xEnumerator.Current;
        y = y0 + (y1 - y0) * (x - x0) / (x1 - x0);
        newSeries1X.Add(x);
        newSeries1Y.Add(y);
        hasS2 = s2xEnumerator.MoveNext();
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry if I don't understand your answer, but x2 is not a constant value. It's given by the points that exist in one set but not in the other. So first I think I have to compare both series of points... By the way, that is a very interesting method. Thanks.

Comment: @Sturm I'm afraid I don't fully understand your question. But you may want to look into the `Except` method instead of `Union` for calculating `x2`. This is actually easier with `doubles` than it would be with points (you'd need a custom `IEqualityComparer`)

Comment: Hello again, I've updated the question with some more information. I wish you could take a look. Thanks

Comment: Ah, and I'm not using the point class because I have more that Yvalue for each X, I also have Real and Imaginary parts. I think I could make a class for that in future..

Comment: @Sturm I think I understand the problem a bit better now. See my updated answer for a solution that should work for you. It's fundamentally similar to yours, but it only requires iterating each list once. I think I can also turn this into an equivalent solution using enumerators, but it'll take me a little time to figure out the edge cases.

Comment: Thank you very much. I've struggled with this one day or two and finally could write the partial solution (using Point class as you suggested). Its very similar to yours. The KEY is to use two different counters, each for one series. I've also check the first j index if the series2 started before series1. Anyway, thank you very much, and sorry for not posting my answer with the code, I wanted to finish it before uploading it.

Comment: @Sturm my solution handles the case of the first `x` of series2 coming before the first `x` of series one with the line `int k = (i == 0) ? i : i - 1`, which was a little tricky. Note, this solution works just as well if you have two different lists of `x`/`y` values or a single list of `DataPoint` objects. I've also updated my answer to remove an unnecessary else-if from the index-based solution and provide an enumerator-based solution for completeness. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

For working with two series with different spacing I first need to generate points in the first set, then in the second (with the same method) and finally sum point to point.

Here is the code for that method:

```
using OxyPlot.Series;
using OxyPlot;

namespace Algorithm1
{

    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            List<DataPoint> S1 = new List<DataPoint> ();
            List<DataPoint> S2 = new List<DataPoint>();
            List<DataPoint> NS1 = new List<DataPoint>();

            S1.Add(new DataPoint(4, 10));
            S1.Add(new DataPoint(6, 20));
            S1.Add(new DataPoint(8, 15));
            S1.Add(new DataPoint(9, 70));
            S1.Add(new DataPoint(10, 5));

            S2.Add(new DataPoint(1, 0));
            S2.Add(new DataPoint(2, 0));
            S2.Add(new DataPoint(3, 0));
            S2.Add(new DataPoint(6, 0));
            S2.Add(new DataPoint(7, 0));
            S2.Add(new DataPoint(8.1, 0));
            S2.Add(new DataPoint(8.2, 0));
            S2.Add(new DataPoint(8.3, 0));
            S2.Add(new DataPoint(8.4, 0));
            S2.Add(new DataPoint(9, 0));
            S2.Add(new DataPoint(9.75, 0));
            S2.Add(new DataPoint(11, 0));
            S2.Add(new DataPoint(12, 0));
            S2.Add(new DataPoint(16, 0));

           NS1 = GetMiddlePoints(S1, S2);
           foreach (DataPoint pointin NS1)
           {
               MessageBox.Show( point.X.ToString()+" : "+ point.Y.ToString());
           }


        }

        #region GetMiddlePoints
        private List<DataPoint> GetMiddlePoints(List<DataPoint> S1, List<DataPoint> S2)
        {
            List<DataPoint> NS1 = new List<DataPoint>();

            int i = 0;
            int j = S2.TakeWhile(p => p.X < S1[0].X).Count();


            int PointsInS1 = S1.Count;
            int PointsInS2 = S2.Count;

            DataPoint newPoint = new DataPoint();


            while (i < PointsInS1 )
            {
                if (j < PointsInS2 )
                {
                    if (S1[i].X < S2[j].X)
                    {
                        newPoint = S1[i];
                        NS1.Add(newPoint );
                        i++;
                    }

                    else if (S1[i].X == S2[j].X)
                    {
                        newPoint = S1[i];
                        NS1.Add(newPoint );
                        i++;
                        j++;
                    }

                    else if (S1[i].X > S2[j].X)
                    {
                        newPoint .X = S2[j].X;
                        newPoint .Y = S1[i-1].Y + (S2[j].X - S1[i-1].X) * (S1[i].Y - S1[i-1].Y) / (S1[i].X - S1[i-1].X);
                        NS1.Add(newPoint );
                        j++;

                    }

                }

                if (j == PointsInS2 )
                {
                    newPoint = S1[i];
                    NS1.Add(newPoint );
                    i++;
                }


            }


            return NS1;

        }

        #endregion

    }
}
```